# Python: how to make an operation between 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` containing the information of the same items but some elements of in `df1` could not appear in `df2`.

For istance:

```
df1 
     id count
0     5  124
1     3  136
2     7  12
3     2  345 


df2 
     id count
0     5  65
1     7  3
```

I would like to compute the fraction `df1['count']/df2['count']` only for the elements that exists and `0` otherwise

```
df3 
     id count
0     5  1.91
1     3  0
2     7  4
3     2  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for new `Series` which is divided by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and last for not matched `id` are created `NaN`s, which are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['count'] = df1['count'].div(df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['count'])).fillna(0)
print (df1)
   id     count
0   5  1.907692
1   3  0.000000
2   7  4.000000
3   2  0.000000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['count']))
0    65.0
1     NaN
2     3.0
3     NaN
Name: id, dtype: float64
```